# add a line to matplotlib subplots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I would like to do a subplot of two figures with matplotlib and add a horizontal line in both. This is probably basic, but I don't know how to specify that one of the lines should be drawn in the first figure, they both end up in the last one. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

s1= pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
s2= pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)

f1= s1.plot(ax=axes[0])
l1=plt.axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--')
l1.set_label('l1')

f2= s1.plot(ax=axes[1])
l2=plt.axhline(0.7,color='red',ls='--') 
l2.set_label('l2')

plt.legend()
```

[image: subplot with horizontal lines]

axhline does not have "ax" as an argument, as the pandas plot function does. So this would work:

```
l1=plt.axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--',ax=axes[0])
```

I read [the examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) in matplotlib and I tried with this other option that does not work either (probably for good reasons)

```
axes[0].plt.axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--')
```

How should I do to draw lines in subplots? Ideally with a legend Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `axes[0].axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--')`? This should work.

Comment: Yes! thanks @NickBecker ! I only need to fix the issue of the legend appearing in the two subplots :-). I might erase the question because I realise it is a bit stupid.

Comment: What about if I want a diagonal line of some kind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with the help of @Nick Becker I answered my own "syntax" question.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline


s1= pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
s2= pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)

f1= s1.plot(ax=axes[0],label='s1')
l1=axes[0].axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--')
l1.set_label('l1')

axes[0].legend(loc='best')

f2= s1.plot(ax=axes[1],label='s2')

l2=axes[1].axhline(0.5,color='black',ls='--')

l2.set_label('l2')

axes[1].legend(loc='best')
```

[image: subplots with horizontal lines]